# How can I tell if SqliteConnection created the database?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Using SqliteConnection.Open() creates the database file if needed, but I can't seem to figure out a way to determine whether or not it was created.

The filename I am passing in is a simple filename ("mydatabase.db") without any absolute path. SqliteConnection creates the file in some directory, but I don't know how to figure out what logic it is using to decide where to put the file, so I can't simply check to see if the file exists before I open it.

Frank

Comment: It should create the database in the same folder where your application starts. If this is a desktop app and you are running inside VS then look at the BIN\DEBUG folder

Comment: If @Steve's solution doesn't work, can't you just add some data to the store to indicate when it was created? (Check if said data exists in the SQLite DB, if not, add it, if it does, it wasn't created by opening this connection)

Comment: Try using `File.Exists()` *before* opening the connection. If you're not building the connection string yourself, use `SqliteConnectionStringBuilder` to parse it and get the file path from the `DataSource` property.

Comment: For what purpose you want this? If for initial seed data initialization - I avise you using lazy initialization (getOrAdd) or create a short table with serialized id of action (or perhaps action itself) and status of it's completion, then run it. The reason behind this - you can migrate data not only once file created, but when you update your SQL schema too. EF Core do this and other ORM frameworks too. And ofcourse it is cross-db approach.

Comment: The reason I can't just use File.Exists() is because I don't know what the full path to the file will be. I'm passing in a simple name without a path. I can search my hard drive to figure out where the file got created, but I don't know how to reconstruct that path in code.

Comment: The reason is because my users occasionally delete the database file from the file system outside of my program and I need to know when this has happened.

Comment: I've resorted to using database queries to detect whether the objects that should be there exist. This works but seems like overkill -- the SqliteConnection class knows whether or not it just created a file. It should be able to tell me.

Comment: Microsoft's "Sqlite" provider uses the same definition of "current directory" as `File.Exists()`. Try it (like I just did) -- using the same file name without a path in the connection string and `File.Exists()`, it returned `false` before opening and `true` after opening.

Comment: I tested the official "SQLite" provider, System.Data.SQLite, and it behaves the same, for what it's worth.

Comment: I did try File.Exists() with the same file name, but it returns false even when the database file does exist.